# Perl - Networking - how can I deal with more than 128 sockets SOMAXCONN?

Tags: perl, nonblocking

I hate this situation (MACOSX)

```
$ perl -MSocket -le 'print SOMAXCONN'
128
```

How can I deal with more than 128 sockets? I'm using IO::Socket::INET (multiplexing with IO::Select at this time) but I have this limitation.

I was thinking in pre-fork N process (each dealing with 128 using select or poll) but I don't know if it can work. Some Ideas?

Comment: Use my system! I get 2,147,483,647, i.e. 32-bit signed. I guess it's a property of the platform, but I'm not the one to ask

Comment: It's a configurable setting on many systems: http://serverfault.com/questions/271380/how-can-i-increase-the-value-of-somaxconn

Comment: @duskwuff humm... I was thinking in some solution in perl but in TCP/IP i think it is not possible.

Comment: *SOMAXCONN does not limit the number of sockets* your process can have open.  Instead, [*it limits a socket's backlog of pending connections*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/listen.html).  How do you know you've exceeded SOMAXCONN?  The ordinary socket API certainly doesn't know this.  What are your symptoms?  Are you sure you aren't simply hitting OS X's frugal RLIMIT_NOFILE, easily remedied with `ulimit -n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a configurable limitation at the OS X kernel level.  Fortunately its pretty easy to fix, but only if you have root.  Here's [an article explaining how to tweak the kernel configuration](https://rolande.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/performance-tuning-the-network-stack-on-mac-osx-10-6/).  The relevant entry is `kern.ipc.somaxconn`.

Otherwise you can try using threads, not sure if each thread gets its own allocation of sockets, or any number of [pre-forking servers on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=fork%20server).

Comment: I realize the Socket::SOMAXCONN() returns a constant, if I change the value in kern.ipc.somaxconn I don't a portable way to identify this. I can read from a configuration file, at least it how Net::Server::Proto::TCP does. My intention is understand how non blocking I/O works with tcp sockets, in special the select/poll mechanism. Thanks Schwern

Comment: Caution, the linked article falsely and offhandedly describes SOMAXCONN as the "maximum number of sockets that can be open at any one time."  See my comment to the original post.